# Deploying to Windows Azure

Tags: eclipse, jsf, netbeans, azure, glassfish

I have created a JSF web application in Netbeans to run on glassfish and I am trying to get it to deploy to Windows Azure.  I imported the .war file into Eclipse and tried deploying to Windows Azure which shows everything is fine and Windows Azure shows that it was uploaded and running but when i try to go to the web site it gives a 404 error.  Are there any steps that must be done prior to pushing to Windows Azure in Eclipse?

Comment: Is your GlassFish server currently installed and running in your Windows Azure server? Can you access to the default page of this GlassFish server?

Comment: Yes, I can see the page saying "your glassfish server is running".  But if I try to add the full path to the URL /JavaMessenger2/faces/login.xhtml I get nothing.  Also I get nothing leaving off /faces/login.xhtml

Comment: Are you sure your FacesServlet filter is `/faces/*`? Maybe if you change it to `*.xhtml` and access to your pages like `http://yourServerAddress<:port>/JavaMessenger2/login.xhtml` you could see your page.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, we tried several things and the best was to simply use a virtual machine and setup a server.  However, we ran out of time on our trial and the class is over, but thanks for the help.